# How will 64 bit variable be referenced in a 32 bit process?

Tags: memory, kernel, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64 bit kernel and i run 32 bit processes in userland.In the user process code ,if i declare a 64 bit variable ,how will it be referred.Will it incur 2 memory reads.?
basically the scenario is:
I need to use a 64 bit mask in my user process.
Approach 1 :
-> Use a u64bits variable.
Approach
-> Use a array of 2 32 bit variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: the kernel has no bearing on the answer to this question.

Second, I assume this is x86 you're talking about. Where possible, the compiler will place 64-bit values across 2 32-bit registers. For example, if you return a `uint64_t` from a function, the low 32 bits will be stored in the `eax` register, and the high bits will be in `edx`.

The compiler will generally do the right thing for performance and correctness: using an array will likely just confuse it and lead to worse results.

By the way, x86-64 CPUs will normally perform reads of 2 adjacent 32-bit words at the same speed as a single 64-bit read. The advantages of 64-bit mode are that *arithmetic* can be done directly on 64-bit values (1 64x64 multiplication instruction vs 3-4 32x32 instructions), there is much more space available in registers (16 registers instead of 8, registers are twice as wide), and of course the larger possible virtual address space.